# How can I delete or update a record sql from JTable in Java Swing

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, jtable

I'm coding on a java Swing sql project. I'm stuck at deleting and updating an information record. I can add a new record normally but can't update or delete one. When I delete, it will notify 'can't find column number'. Here is my code and a picture of the error message. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
private void JtbDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  int row = jtbStudent.getSelectedRow();
    String cell = jtbStudent.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
    try {
        stm = cnn.createStatement();
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?", "WARNING",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        stm.execute("DELETE FROM Student where RollNo = " + cell);
        loadTable();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delete Successfully");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delete Unsuccesfully!");
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    finally{
        try {
            stm.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Update button

```
 private void jbtUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       
  try {
        int row = jtbStudent.getSelectedRow();
        String cell = jtbStudent.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
        stm = cnn.createStatement();
        String value1 = jtxName.getText();
        String value2 = jtxMark.getText();
        String sql="UPDATE Student set Name='"+value1+"' ,mark='"+value2+"' 
,where RollNo = '" + cell + "'";
        stm.execute(sql);
        System.out.println("Update success!");
        loadTable();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) topic for more information.

Comment: Please remove the screenshot. It shows personal information (including marks in relation to people).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an invalid SQL-statement. The line you are writing (and sending to the database) is `DELETE FROM Student where RollNo = A02`.

What you expect (in valid SQL) would be: `DELETE FROM Student where RollNo = 'A02'`.

Now for simplicity, you could use

```java
stm.execute("DELETE FROM Student where RollNo = '" + cell + "'");
```

But that would be open to SQL injection, meaning that if the String in the variable `cell` could read something like `"'; drop table student;"`, your database would drop the students table.

Better use the prepared statement (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```java
PreparedStatement stm = cnn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Student where RollNo = ?");
stm.setString(1, cell);
boolean result = stm.execute();
```

This way, the `String` is properly escaped. Please refere to jdbc's documentation for details.

PreparedStatement - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html
Connection - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)

Comment: Remove the ',' from ',where'. That said, you really need to learn to debug your code. This page should answer questions rather than solve bugs.